# Optimal scalability of a distributed algorithm

Tags: runtime-analysis, distributed-systems

What's the optimal scalability of some algorithm when I implement it in a distributed manner?

Intuitively, it seems to me that any algorithm can scale at most linearly with number of computing nodes. I.e, if algorithm A takes **T** units of time with **1 computing node** on input I, it can't run faster than **T/n** units of time  with **n computing nodes** on the same input I.

Is my intuition correct or are there some weird counter-examples to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your intuition is correct, for all the reasonable models of computation that I'm familiar with.  If it weren't, then we could take a single machine and have it simulate a cluster of n nodes, increasing the cost by only a factor of n.  So, if you had an algorithm that ran on a cluster of n nodes faster than T/n, you'd get an algorithm that runs on a single node faster than T.

Note that the single node might need to have n times as much memory as each node in the cluster.